# Discord.py copying user's messages and saying them

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
if message.author.id != USER ID HERE:
    msg = client.get_message(message, message.author)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

I want the bot to copy people's message and then say them. (just to troll some good friends. anyway,) With this code the bot replies when they say something, but with "" instead of the exact same message.

Some help here, please?

Comment: What is"USER ID HERE" replaced with in your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the contents of a message (as opposed to a `Message` object) with `Message.content`

```
await client.send_message(message.channel, message.content)
```